# Formatting JSON table from Postgresql request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I'm trying to create a Json format from a postgresql request.

Firstly I have used Rails to request my database in the **format.json** block of my controller and then used a **json.builder** file to format the json view. It worked until my requests return hundreds of thousands rows, so I searched how to optimize the json creation, avoiding all the ActiveRecord stack.

To do this I am using Postgresql 9.6 json functions to get directly my data in the right format, which is for example :

```
SELECT array_to_json('{{1157241840,-1.95},{1157241960,-1.96}}'::float[]);
[[1157241840, -1.95], [1157241960, -1.96]]
```

But using data from  this kind of request :

```
SELECT date,value FROM measures;
```

The best I could obtain was something like this :

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(t)) FROM (SELECT date,value FROM measures) t;
```

Resulting in :

```
[
 {"date":"1997-06-13T19:12:00","value":1608.4},
 {"date":"1997-06-13T19:12:00","value":-0.6}
]
```

which is quite different ... How would you build this SQL request ?
Thanks for your help !

My measures table look like this :

```
      id | value |          created_at        |         updated_at         | parameter_id | quality_id | station_id |          date       | campain_id | elevation | sensor_id | comment_id  
 --------+-------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------
  799634 | -1.99 | 2017-02-21 09:41:09.062795 | 2017-02-21 09:41:09.118807 |            2 |            |          1 | 2006-06-26 23:24:00 |          1 |      -5.0 |           |
 1227314 | -1.59 | 2017-02-21 09:44:12.032576 | 2017-02-21 09:44:12.088311 |            2 |            |          1 | 2006-11-30 19:48:00 |          1 |      -5.0 |           |           
 1227315 | 26.65 | 2017-02-21 09:44:12.032576 | 2017-02-21 09:44:12.088311 |            3 |            |          1 | 2006-11-30 19:48:00 |          1 |      -5.0 |           |
```

Comment: show sample of measures..

Comment: `id   | value |         created_at         |         updated_at         | parameter_id | quality_id | station_id |        date         | campain_id | elevation | sensor_id | comment_id  
    799634 | -1.99 | 2017-02-21 09:41:09.062795 | 2017-02-21 09:41:09.118807 |            2 |            |          1 | 2006-06-26 23:24:00 |          1 |      -5.0 |           |`

Comment: Sorry for the bad indentation, I have not found how to break a line in comments. The header of a measure stop at "comment_id" and the sample starts at 799634.

Comment: please, update your question with fields, not comment. also when I run your example, I get error: `t=# SELECT array_to_json('{{1157241840,-1.95},{1157241960,-1.96}}'::int[]);
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "-1.95"
LINE 1: SELECT array_to_json('{{1157241840,-1.95},{1157241960,-1.96}...
`

Comment: Indeed, it's not int[] but float[] that I meant. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need array of array you need to use json_build_array:

```
SELECT json_agg(json_build_array(date,value)) FROM measures;
```

If you want convert timestamp to epoch:

```
SELECT json_agg(json_build_array(extract(epoch FROM date)::int8, value)) FROM measures;
```

For test:

```
WITH measures AS (
    SELECT 1157241840 as date, -1.95 as value
     UNION SELECT 1157241960, -1.96
     UNION SELECT 1157241980, NULL
) 


SELECT json_agg(json_build_array(date,value)) FROM measures;


                            json_agg                            
----------------------------------------------------------------
 [[1157241840, -1.95], [1157241960, -1.96], [1157241980, null]]
```

Comment: The test is working for me, the json_build_array or jsonb_build_array with my database also. But when I try to build the array of array with json_agg or array_agg I just have an empty result.

Comment: Could you try json_agg for some data from your table? Try to do it with one row.

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed a problem with the json_agg format, the less output on my terminal was not showing the result and I don't know why. By making the test for just one row I have noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table measures (date timestamp, value float);
insert into measures (date, value) values
(to_timestamp(1157241840),-1.95),
(to_timestamp(1157241960),-1.96);

select array_to_json(array_agg(array[extract(epoch from date), value]::float[]))
from measures
;
              array_to_json              
-----------------------------------------
 [[1157241840,-1.95],[1157241960,-1.96]]
```